# Emit/Execute from observable A,when observable B emits an item

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a non completing Observable A.I need to emit from another Observable B whenever A changes.

For example.

```
//Stream of changed items
Observable<Item> a;
//Completing observable which provides list of items
Observable<List<Item>> b;

/**
 * Returns a non-completing Observable of all new and updated items.
 */
@NonNull
public Observable<T> getStream() {
   //Implementation here
}



/**
*Returns a non-completing observable of the list
*/

//My implementation
public void Observable<List<Item>> getListStream(){
   return getStream().flatMap(item->getAll());

}


/**
*Returns a completing observable of the list of all items
*/
public void getAll(){
 //Implementation here
}
```

Here B is a completing observable.

This is the from [Reark github project](https://github.com/reark/reark/)  from [SingleItemContentProviderStore.java](https://github.com/reark/reark/blob/master/reark/src/main/java/io/reark/reark/data/store/SingleItemContentProviderStore.java)

The problem with this approach is:
The getStream() returns an observable which emits the upserted items ,and hence the `getAll` method is called everytime there is a change in the list. Which means adding 100 items to the list,triggers the getListStream() observable 100 times.I understand this approach is wrong,could there be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

if B is completing then I suppose It should have signature `Observable<Observable<List<Item>>>`:

`Observable<Observable<List<Item>>> b = a.map(ignored -> getListStream())`

Then It can be used as follows:

`b.subscribe(obs -> obs.subscribe(itemsList -> {}));`

Comment: No need; use flatMap() instead of map().

Comment: Yes I ended up using flatMap() for this purpose. However It seems to be quite inefficient, I'll edit the question and add my implementation.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos OP wants B to be completable: if you know how to achieve that with flatmap there is plenty of room for answers

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Observable<List<Item>> cachedObs = null;

public void Observable<List<Item>> getListStream(){
  if(cachedObs == null) {
    cachedObs = getStream().take(1).flatMap(item->getAll()).cache();
  }
  return cachedObs;
}
```

This will call getAll() after the observable of getStream() emits the first item, and it will cache the result across all subscriptions to the same observable.